# W10 Universal: how to play a song from disk using Backgroundaudio?

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal, background-audio, known-folders

The Microsoft W10 Universal apps Background Audio sample can play a list of .wma files stored in ///Assets, like this:

```
var song2 = new SongModel();
song2.Title = "Ring 2";
song2.MediaUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Media/Ring02.wma");
song2.AlbumArtUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Media/Ring02.jpg");
playlistView.Songs.Add(song2);
```

But I can't get the program to play .wma files stored on disk. I tried to select a file using the FileOpenPicker, assign it to StorageFile file and then:

```
if (file != null)
{
Uri uri = new Uri(file.Path);
song2.MediaUri = uri;
}
```

or by (temporary) placing it in the Pictures library (which I checked in the capabilities) which I thought I could access like this but either that's not the case or it doesn't work (and most likely both):

```
string name = "ms-appdata:///local/images/SomeSong.wma";
Uri uri = new Uri(name, UriKind.Absolute);
song1.MediaUri = uri;
```

Only the original ///Assets WMA is audible.

What should I change? And how can I convert a KnownFolders directory to a Uri?

Answer (score 0):

The Background Audio sample uses [MediaSource.CreateFromUri method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.core.mediasource.createfromuri) to create media source. While using this method, the parameter can only be set to the Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) of a file that is included with the app or the URI of a file on the network. To set the source to a file retrieved from the local system by using a [FileOpenPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.aspx) object, we can use [MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.core.mediasource.createfromstoragefile) method. And whenever our app accesses a file or folder through a picker, we can add it to app's [FutureAccessList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207457) or [MostRecentlyUsedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207458) to keep track of it.

For example, after we get the `StorageFile` from `FileOpenPicker`, we can add it to `FutureAccessList` and store the token that the app can use later to retrieve the storage item in app's local settings like:

```
if (file != null)
{
    var token = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(file);

    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["song1"] = token;
}
```

For more info about `FutureAccessList`, please see [Track recently used files and folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/how-to-track-recently-used-files-and-folders).

Then in `BackgroundAudioTask`, I changed `CreatePlaybackList` method to replace the original like:

```
private async void CreatePlaybackList(IEnumerable<SongModel> songs)
{
    // Make a new list and enable looping
    playbackList = new MediaPlaybackList();
    playbackList.AutoRepeatEnabled = true;

    // Add playback items to the list
    foreach (var song in songs)
    {
        MediaSource source;
        //Replace Ring 1 to the song we select
        if (song.Title.Equals("Ring 1"))
        {
            var file = await Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["song1"].ToString());
            source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
        }
        else
        {
            source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(song.MediaUri);
        }
        source.CustomProperties[TrackIdKey] = song.MediaUri;
        source.CustomProperties[TitleKey] = song.Title;
        source.CustomProperties[AlbumArtKey] = song.AlbumArtUri;
        playbackList.Items.Add(new MediaPlaybackItem(source));
    }

    // Don't auto start
    BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.AutoPlay = false;

    // Assign the list to the player
    BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Source = playbackList;

    // Add handler for future playlist item changes
    playbackList.CurrentItemChanged += PlaybackList_CurrentItemChanged;
}
```

This is just a simple sample, you may need to change the `SongModel` and some other code to implement your own player. For more info about Background Audio, you can also refer to [The Basics of Background Audio](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/01/13/the-basics-of-background-audio/). Besides, with Windows 10, version 1607, significant improvements were made to the media playback APIs,  including a simplified single-process design for background audio. You can see [Play media in the background](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio) to check the new feature.